# Apache Cordova InAppBrowser.executeScript not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, cordova

Делаю первое приложения на Apach Cordova (Visual Studio 2017), пытаюсь открыть сайт и нажать на нём на кнопку:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
      ref.executeScript({ code: 'var ttt = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default")[0]; ttt.click();' });
    });
  };
```

при выполнении кода вижу ошибку в консоли: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4400" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
Как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: Это не ошибка, а сообщение о блокировке небезопасных действий скрипта... в соответствии с политикой same-origin.

Comment: Как его обойти?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov почитайте про CORS.

Comment: @EVG, прочитал, получается если на сервере не разрешены CORS запросы, ничего не получится. Нет ли каких других вариантов решить задачу?

Comment: Хорошая статья про CORS: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/